# Rycote Hex Head Key?

Tags: windshield, wind, windscreens

I have been using the Rode Blimp for a while but I just picked up a new Mic (Sanken Css5) and a Rycote windscreen.  The Rycote comes with something called a "Hex Head Key", anyone know what this little guy is used for?

It looks like a 2 inch plastic figure eight, with one half having a hexagon shape and the other half an incomplete circle.  The Hex appears to fit the bottom of the mic stand attachment that can be used instead of the pistol grip.  But I can not figure out what the purpose is.  I am sure it is something so obvious that it is right in front of my face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the purpose is that you can fix the end of the short XLR cable coming out of the blimp. That way it doesn't dangle around.

Nevertheless I have never used that mic stand attachment, since I use the pistol grip instead. Of course it's easier to damage the thread of the pistol grip than the mic stand attachment when you mount it on a boom pole in a hurry, but I am always very cautious not to do any damage to it.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think it's for moving the 2 mic clip mounts closer together or further away from each other?

The hex-screw is at the bottom of the circle above the silver bar the Blimp fits on to.

Comment: The windshield came with a screwdriver with a hexagon bit point that is definitely for moving the mounts. Maybe that is what the Hex Head Key is.  But my question is about something else (it thought was called the Hex Head Key but now I guess I don't know what it is called) included that I am not sure what it is.  If you go to http://www.rycote.com/products/full_windshield_kit/ I am asking about the plastic doo-hickey in the picture above the screwdriver and to the left of the windshield extension.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
I know exactly what this is, and the above answer and absolutely correct. I use this method sometimes as it makes the 'blimp' ever so slightly lighter and takes 15 or so cm off the length of the boom, which is often very useful. But the clip is to hold the XLR, it's HEX as that is the shape of the bracket. Here is a (not very good) picture:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me figure it out.  Once you see what it is for it makes perfect sense.
